# .htaccess question - document root - Do we need this RewriteRule in here?

Tags: .htaccess, documentroot

On our virtual host, we have defined our document root to point to `var/www/something/public`

**Since we have that, do we need, on our .htaccess file (that will be placed on public directory btw), this?**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule .? /public%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: If my questions doesn't make sense, please let me know as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. you don't need specify rewrite rules in .htaccess for this case.

Suppose you have a file named index.html in var/www/domain/public and you configured this directory as the DocumentRoot for 1sample1.com.

Then http://1sample1.com/index.html will work.

Comment: Correct me I'm wrong: I may need to specify rewrite rules in .htaccess files. But don't need *this particular rule* because it's redundant. Is that it?

Comment: Actually you need not to worry about the folder name "public". Setting DocumentRoot means all files in DocumentRoot must serve for every http request.

Comment: True, but If I need to redirect to a specific file, for example, for index.php especificly, and if I would like to avoid hotlinking on hosted images, for those both cases, I would need to have a rewrite rule, but the one on my question, that one, in particular, is redundant. Yes? - I'm just trying to make perfectly clear and be certain that I'm not making rules on my htaccess file that I don't need to. Hence all this questioning. :)

Comment: Since you have already specified the document root to be the following  /var/www/domain/public you dont have to explicitly write these rules in the .htaccess as both means the same.